# Option "symbol" in scattermapbox is not working

Tags: python, google-maps, scatter-plot

I am trying to change the symbol from circle to location pin to highlight the co-ordinates on to the map.However, apart from "circle" no other options work correctly in the symbol option.
I have tried - square,marker, triangle.Can someone tell me how to fix this, it doesnt throw an error

```
#Plotting co-ordinates on to the map
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox
            (
            lat=df["Latitude"],
            lon=df["Longitude"],
            mode='markers',
            marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker
                (
                       size=10,
                       color =  df['Size'],
                       colorscale = 'RdYlGn_r',
                       showscale=True,
                       symbol = 'star'
                 )
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that markers different from "circle" (default) work only if you are using "vector tiles from the Mapbox service" (e.g. "dark" or "satellite") for which your mapbox token needs to be provided; but they don't work if you are using "open" vector tiles" like "open-street-map"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's impossible to set both a non-circle symbol and a marker color at once.

> Note that the array marker.color and marker.size are only available
> for “circle” symbols.

Source: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox.html

Answer (score 0):

In the plotly documentation they do this using another syntax, have you tried that already?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

token = open(".mapbox_token").read() # you need your own token

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+text+lines",
    lon = [-75, -80, -50], lat = [45, 20, -20],
    marker = {'size': 20, 'symbol': ["bus", "harbor", "airport"]},
    text = ["Bus", "Harbor", "airport"],textposition = "bottom right"))

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'accesstoken': token,
        'style': "outdoors", 'zoom': 0.7},
    showlegend = False)

fig.show()
```

Source: https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/#set-marker-symbols